# cURL - What will be the contents of the HTTP request?

Tags: rest, curl

By invoking this cURL:

```
curl -D- -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@myfile.png" http://myhost/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-123/attachments
```

I'm especially interested in the contents of the message-body and the Content-type (or other headers). I need to know how/what syntax the file contents will be "embedded" into the request.

Comment: Did you try to make a network capture with wireshark?

Comment: add `--trace-ascii filedump.txt` to the command line and see exactly what curl sent and received...

Answer (score 1):

Flag `--verbose` is used to see the whole request